# How to save a trained machine learning model in python and load it in C++ for prediction?

Tags: python, c++, machine-learning, scikit-learn, joblib

This code will  help you to get the model.pkl file that I need to open in C++

```
# Load libraries
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.externals import joblib

# Load data
iris = datasets.load_iris()
features = iris.data
target = iris.target

# Create decision tree classifer object
classifer = RandomForestClassifier()

# Train model
model = classifer.fit(features, target)

# Save the model as pickle file
joblib.dump(model, "model.pkl")
```

So, from the above code, we got model.pkl file, which is a machine learning model (random forest classifier). Now I need to read model.pkl file using C++ and test the model using sample data (new_observation). I can do it in python as follows:

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib
# Load model from file 
classifer = joblib.load("model.pkl")
# Create new observation
new_observation = [[ 5.2,  3.2,  1.1,  0.1]]
# Predict observation's class
classifer.predict(new_observation)
```

But need to do this using C++, basically, I need equivalent code of the above 4 lines (python to C++) which I don't know.

Comment: This seems like a fairly specific question about one particular library. You have however not shown any form of effort in doing any kind of research on the subject yourself, which is expected before posting a question here. I would add a lot more details of what exactly it is you need/want. "Implement it in C++" is very vague.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look into avenues to store the model in an [interoperable format](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/model_persistence.html#interoperable-formats) like ONNX or PMML, which might be readable by a library from a completely different environment.

Whether this works for the case of a `RandomForestClassifier` I do not know, though.

Comment: I support this answer, try saving it in ONNX i know many libraries in CPP can run prediction with this format like libtorch, etc. and visualize with openCV